# Do products exist in CRing

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Do categorical products exist in CRing? I know they do in Ring, but that doesn't imply they exist here I believe.

Comment: Hint: The inclusion functor $i:\textbf{CRing}\to\textbf{Ring}$ is full, so it suffices to show that the products defined in $\textbf{Ring}$ are commutative so long as the rings being multiplied are.

Comment: The usual direct product works.

Comment: Products, and in fact all limits and colimits, exist in any category of algebraic objects, i.e. objects that can be described by an equational theory. (Fields, for example, *don't* count since they require *in*equations, but commutative rings in general certainly do count.)

Comment: To add on Derek Elkins's comment, the limits are actually preserved and created by the forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins Can you touch on what you mean by your comment about fields and inequations?

Comment: @Randall The general theory I'm referencing is the theory of [Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) and its generalizations. The definition of fields include axioms like $x\neq 0\implies xx^{-1}=1$. The partiality of $(-)^{-1}$ is not a problem - essentially algebraic theories also allow partial operations, but the fact that its domain is specified by an inequality *is* a problem. Technically speaking, (discrete) fields require [coherent logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+logic) while essentially algebraic theories only require cartesian logic.